# Como saber si un break ha sido ejecutado

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Buenas, tengo una duda y no encuentro respuesta por ningún lado. El caso es que tengo en un script un bucle `for` en el que tengo una condición con una sentencia `break`. Lo que me gustaría saber es si hay alguna forma de saber si la sentecia `break` se ha ejecutado o no, sin hacer uso de variables auxiliares o de varaibles lógicas.

Este es el ejemplo:

```js
var array = [];
var variable;

for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
  if (array[i] === variable) {
    variable = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

¿Hay alguna manera de evaluar si la sentencia break se ha ejecutado en este código? ¿Devuelve de alguna manera un valor booleano?

Comment: No, no hay ninguna forma de hacer esto, (sin algún elemento adicional como un flag) en javascript. (En javascript no existe el `for...else` de Python).

Comment: siempre puedes imprimir algo antes y despues del break, el valor de i por ejemplo. Si te salta el break solo te pintará una vez el último valor de i, pero no se de javascript, no se si e servirá de algo

Comment: Si el `break` está dentro de un if... sabes que se ejecutó si se cumple la condicion ..

Comment: Si, lo sé. Pero quería saber si la sentencia break devolvía de alguna manera valores booleanos para evaluarla, pero visto lo visto no se puede. Ahora entiendo por qué no encontraba nada de nada.

Comment: `break` es una sentencia, no un método. Si te sirve para algo adicional, puedes poner una etiqueta antes de tu ciclo (ej: `loop1`), y en la condición que hace que termine, le puedes agregar a la sentencia `break` como parámetro adicional esa misma etiqueta (`break loop1;`). Ver (MDN):  [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)

Comment: Los `label` y los `break` deberían evitarse en la medida de lo posible: rompen el flujo del programa y hacen el código inconsistente y más difícil de mantener. Éste código podría hacerse con un `while` y sería más simple y legible.

Comment: Gracias por la apreciación @AlvaroMontoro , la tomaré en cuenta.

Comment: @asantanao En el [chat] se estaba hablando sobre tu pregunta (nada malo), por si te quieres pasar a decir "hola" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que estás buscando algo parecido al `for...else` en Python.
No es posible, en Javascript, sin el uso de alguna otra cosa, saber si el bucle se ha detenido `con normalidad` (Porque ha llegado al final) o porque se detuvo con un `break`.

Pero, ¿Seguro que es lo que quieres comprobar en tu ejemplo? Según tu ejemplo veo que lo quieres comprobar es si ha encontrado un índice.

```js
var array = ['Javascript', 'mola', '=)'];
var variable = 'Javascript';
var index = -1;

for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
  if (array[i] === variable) {
    index = i;
    break;
  }
}

if(index >= 0) {
  // Hacer algo
  console.log('index', index);
} else {
  console.log('No se encontró');
}
```

O mucho más sencillo (ES2015):

```js
var array = ['Javascript', 'no', 'es', 'Python', '=('];
var variable = 'Javascript';

var index = array.findIndex(item => item === variable);

if(index >= 0){
  console.log('index', index);
} else {
  console.log('No se encontró');
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. No estoy buscando un índice, simplemente puse el código mas sencillo de ejemplo para la pregunta que hice. Estaba buscando ahorrar variables y mejorar mi código, pero parece que sin un flag no es posible

Comment: Eso ya dependería de cada caso concreto, en el segundo ejemplo, si no necesitas la variable index, podrías hacer directamente: `if(array.findIndex(...condición...) !== -1){...} else {...}`